# Recreate markdown-style inline code blocks in latex

Tags: spacing, highlighting

I'm trying to recreate markdown-style inline code blocks in latex, you know, `these things`. They should have a slightly highlighted background, but not influence line height or word separation of the text they are defined in. Also, blocks with tall content like `|` should have the same height as others like `-`.

This is my attempt recreating them in latex:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, hidelinks]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\mbox{
    \ttfamily
    \tcbox[
        on line,
        boxsep=0pt, left=4pt, right=4pt, top=2pt, bottom=1.5pt,
        toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt,
        oversize=0pt, enlarge left by=0pt, enlarge right by=0pt,
        colframe=white, colback=black!12
    ]{#1}
}}

\begin{document}

This is a \code{test} for markdown-style \code{code blocks}.

Plus \code{+} Minus \code{-}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this attempt creates extensive word spacing, unwanted space before punctuation, and doesn't have uniform height:

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone tell me how to improve these code blocks?

**EDIT**: The unwanted space can be removed by adding `%` to the end of some lines in the macro. Thanks to @Teepeemm for suggesting this fix in the comments.

Comment: For the spacing before and after, add `%` to the end of some of your lines.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/107497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Tikz`: `baseline`, `anchor=base` and `minimum height`

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661993/recreate-markdown-style-inline-code-blocks-in-latex
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \tikzset{%
        baseline,
        inner sep=2pt,
        minimum height=12pt,
        rounded corners=2pt  
    }
    \newcommand{\code}[1]{\mbox{% added this percent
        \ttfamily
        \tikz \node[anchor=base,fill=black!12]{#1};% added this percent
    }}
    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{%
        baseline,
        inner sep=2pt,
        minimum height=12pt
    }
    This is a \code{test} for markdown-style \code{code blocks} .

    Plus \code{+} Minus \code{-}.
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The left and right spacing is caused by missing `%` at the end of lines in your command definition.  See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/107497)

For the height, I just specified a height to the tcbox; .8 seemed about right.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, hidelinks]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\mbox{% added this percent
    \ttfamily
    \tcbox[
        on line,
        boxsep=0pt, left=4pt, right=4pt, top=2pt, bottom=1.5pt,
        toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt,
        oversize=0pt, enlarge left by=0pt, enlarge right by=0pt,
        colframe=white, colback=black!12,
        height=.8\baselineskip % added this (and guessed at .8)
    ]{#1}% added this percent
}}

\begin{document}

This is a \code{test} for markdown-style \code{code blocks}.

Plus \code{+} Minus \code{-}.

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the `%` works great. However, using `height=.8\baselineskip` doesn't work as this offsets the baseline for all characters. It looks like all characters are now starting `.8\baselineskip` above baseline, and go as far down as they want. Instead, I'd like to not change character position and only set the height of the background if possible.