# How to mimic StackExchange-style inline code in LaTeX

Tags: code

I love the way StackExchange `formats inline code`, using both a `fixed width font` and `a gray background`.

**How can I mimic the above sentence in LaTeX?**

One possibility might be using a combination of the [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings), [`helvet`](https://ctan.org/pkg/helvet), and [`inconsolata`](https://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata) packages (in addition to the [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package). Here is an attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Implement 1-inch margins using 'geometry' package
% ('geometry' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Implement inline code using 'listings' package
% ('listings' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/listings)
\usepackage{listings}

% Implement Helvetica using 'helvet' package
% ('helvet' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/helvet)
% (use code snippet from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121063/15622/)
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Implement Inconsolata, a Consolas-like font, using 'inconsolata' package
% ('inconsolata' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata)
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\section*{Attempt to mimic StackExchange inline code}
\noindent I love the way StackExchange \lstinline|formats inline code|,
using both a \lstinline|fixed width font| and \lstinline|a gray background|.

\end{document}
```

[image: output rendering]

- **However, I'm not sure how to obtain the gray background. How can I do this?**
- **In what other ways can my attempt be improved to mimic StackExchange-style inline code?**

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [Adding background color to \verb or \lstinline command without \Colorbox](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/357227)

Comment: If you are using OpTeX, see OpTeX trick 0009 https://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#inttinoval

Comment: According to the documentation of listings, `\lstinlne` does not support frames or background colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option using `tcolorbox` and `soulpos`, adapted from my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697157/208544). It supports line breaking and any customization available to tcolorbox commands. The command `\mycode` can be used like `\mycode{<code>}` or `\mycode<char><code><char>`, e.g. `\mycode|bla|`, `\mycode!bla!`, ... The latter syntax allows `<code>` to contain `\{` and `\}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{
  on line,
  arc=1pt, outer arc=2pt,
  colback=lightgray!50!white, colframe=lightgray!50!white,
  boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=-1pt, top=2pt, bottom=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt, #1
}

\ulposdef\codeulinner[xoffset-start=1pt]{%
    \ifulstarttype{0}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={leftrule=1pt}}}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={leftrule=0pt,sharp corners=west}}}%
    \ifulendtype{0}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={rightrule=1pt}}}%
        {\tcbset{ULsiderule/.append style={rightrule=0pt,sharp corners=east}}}%
    \mybox[ULsiderule]{\vphantom{Ap}\rule{\ulwidth}{0pt}}%
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycode}{v}{%
  \begingroup\ttfamily
  \codeulinner{#1}%
  \endgroup%
  }

\begin{document}

Some code: \mycode{\command _^%&}

Some text. \mycode{This is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long inline code.} Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: code]

Correct output will require two compilations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "Undefined control sequence" from `\NewDocumentCommand`. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: @Andrew Your tex distribution is probably out of date. Try updating

Comment: I learned that including `\usepackage{xparse}` in the preamble allowed me to use `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @Andrew Yes that works, however the xparse commands have been available in the kernel since October 2020 so you should really consider updating your distribution

Answer (score 10):

A solution which requires the use of LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Code}{v}{\highLight[gray!20]{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

I love the way StackExchange \Code!formats inline code!, using both a \Code!fixed width font! and 
\Code!a gray background!. 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

There is the `soul` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul, xcolor}
\colorlet{tsecolor}{gray!20}
\sethlcolor{tsecolor}

\newcommand{\tse}[1]{\hl{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent I love the way StackExchange \tse{formats inline code},
using both a \tse{fixed width font} and \tse{a gray background}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `soul` and verbatim mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
    \setul{2ex}{3.5ex}%
    \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
    \SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\Code}{v}{%
  \begingroup\ttfamily
  \sethlcolor{black!15}%
  \hl{\,\,#1\,\,}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\Code!\LaTeX{\{| y{!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here, I adapt the `censor` package, to introduce `\seh` (stack-exchange highlight).  The result handles line breaking.  I note that while (in my case) the TeXworks viewer shows the result in a somewhat choppy fashion, looking at the PDF with a PDF viewer such as Adobe (shown in the result below) presents as intended.

A bonus of the `censor` approach is that most inline math can also be handled directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor,xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\censorcolor{gray!30}
\censorruledepth=-.9\dp\strutbox% -0.3ex DEFAULT
\censorruleheight=.9\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox%  2.1ex DEFAULT
\newlength\wo@pb
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength\wo@pb{\widthofpbox{\ttfamily#1}}%
  \censorrule{\wo@pb}\kern-\wo@pb\texttt{#1}}
\def\censpace{{\color{\censorcolor}%
  \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr\censorruleheight+\censorruledepth\relax
    depth -\censorruledepth
  \hskip\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
  \mbox{}}}
\let\sv@censpace\censpace
\let\svcensorrule\censorrule
\renewcommand\censorrule[1]{\textcolor{\censorcolor}{\svcensorrule{#1}}}
\makeatother
\let\seh\xblackout
\begin{document}
I love the way StackExchange \seh{formats inline code}, using both a 
\seh{fixed width font} and \seh{a gray background}.

One can even do this with \seh{inline math: $y=\alpha x^{2\beta} + 1$}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be to eliminate use of the [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package altogether, and use [`tikz`](https://tikz.dev/) to encode gray background, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663945/15622) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661993/).

- A disadvantage is that I don't think it's possible to typeset special characters like braces `{}` and brackets `[]` in this way.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Implement 1-inch margins using 'geometry' package
% ('geometry' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Implement Helvetica using 'helvet' package
% ('helvet' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/helvet)
% (use code snippet from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121063/15622/)
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Implement Inconsolata, a Consolas-like font, using 'inconsolata' package
% ('inconsolata' package: https://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata)
\usepackage{inconsolata}
%\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

% Implement gray background using \mbox and the 'tikz' package 
% ('tikz' package: https://tikz.dev/)
% (use code snippet from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663945/15622)
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  baseline,
  inner sep=2pt,
  minimum height=12pt,
  rounded corners=2pt
}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\mbox{%
  \ttfamily
  \tikz \node[anchor=base,fill=black!12]{#1};%
}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Attempt to mimic StackExchange inline code}
\noindent I love the way StackExchange \code{formats inline code},
using both a \code{fixed width font} and \code{a gray background}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output example using tikz]

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not support line breaking.