implement inline code block with tcb
I want to create an inline code block like what is shown in markdown by using `` looking like this.
Here is my approach by using tcolorbox.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{LightGrey}{RGB}{240,244,247}

\newtcbox{\codebox}
{on line, arc = 4pt, outer arc = 5pt,
colback = LightGrey, colframe = LightGrey!80!black,
boxsep = 0pt, left = 1pt, right = 1pt, top = 2pt, bottom = 2pt,
boxrule = 1pt}
\newcommand\code[1]{\codebox{ \texttt{#1} } }

\begin{document}

\code{This is a code box.}

\end{document}

This toy implementation has many problems.

it does not really work as what \verb|| do, however, I cannot simply add it into the command in case there is a | in the text. I need to manually add escape symbol to handle it.

The code block never break lines. I want a behavior like this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence. Since the work break is achieved in markdown(like previous code block), I want to handle it in TeX as well.


I only want to achieve a \verb-like command, so syntax highlight is not necessary, thank you for your help.
I believe that \lstinline could't handle problem 1. \lstinline require me to manually escape brackets as well.
I am using TeX 2024, XeLaTeX as my compiler.

welcome! please complete your code so we can compile it. boxes can't break, so you need to rethink this approach. you probably want to look at code for highlighting text. this is not straightforward, but there are some reasonably good solutions. if luatex is an option, there's a lua package which I've heard is very good. otherwise, soul (or soulutf8?), for example. you're already aware of listings. not sure if fancyverb offers anything for inline?

note that you can alter the delimiter for \verb e.g. if your code using | but not +, you could alter it to use \verb+...+. obviously there has to be some character used to delimit the verbatim input.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700580/how-to-mimic-stackexchange-style-inline-code-in-latex/701279

@cfr, I've modified my code to be compilable.
I came up with the idea just because that soul could achieve multi-line highlight, and I think I could use it as in inline block.
what we've discussed for issue 1 coould be solved by using \mintinline{text}{#1} which actually gets rid of the escape symbol.
Thanks for suggesting fancyvrb package, however, I'm afraid that it doesn't provide  methods of use but a \DefineShortVerb command for me. The key point is to choose a symbol that we won't use in verbatim environment.
Thanks again for your valuable suggestion.

@mbert I've tried the first answer of that post, and it seems to actually works, thank you for pointing out the post for me!
